# Writing C# nunit test without having access to the rest of the code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, moq

I have a class Person and the interface:

```
interface IService
{
    double GetAccDetails(int personId);
}

public class Person
{
    private int _personId;
    private IService _service;

    public Person(int personId, IService service)
    {
        _personId= personId;
        _service = service;
    }

    public double Amount {get; set;}

    public void UpdateBackingAcc()
    {
        Amount = _service.GetAccDetails(_personId);
    }
}
```

And I have to cover this piece of the code with nunit tests, however I don't have access to the service,but only to the code I published.

So my questions are:

1. Should I moque it in order to write the unit tests? If yes, it will always return me some static value so I don't see much profit of it.
2. What kind of tests could be created for the given interface? I assume, one of the tests could try to use `personId1` and get some static value, then it could use `personId2` and maybe get another value and then to check if the amount was updated or not. So if that's correct, this could be only 1 unit test.

Probably it makes sense to check if the value is negative or not... maybe also is the value is 0...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Person` has a public constructor, public get\set property and public method. The recommendation is to test public interface of the class. For you class you can test:

1. Ctor, you should validate `IService` against null. Improve your code to test that.
2. You can test your property get and set
3. You can verify when `UpdateBackingAcc` is called that `IService` will be invoked and the value will be preserved within `Amount` property.

Answer (score 1):

As far as writing **unit tests** go, because you're interacting with a 3rd party service and therefore have no control over it, mocking is your best option.

I personally suggest writing a wrapper class around the service that you can have control of your interaction with that service.

I'd be okay with one test: testing that the value returned by the mocked out service is assigned to `Amount`. It doesn't really matter if the number is zero, positive, or negative since all of those cases go through the same code path.

You may want to have **integration tests** that interact with the service for real, primarily to test that you indeed are communicating with the service and getting values back.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Yes the service is external dependency of tested class and it should be mocked.

2/ Interface can't be tested bacause it has no code. Person class can be tested.

I agree with you. Here you could test the `constructor` and prove that the fields were set properly. But only reasonable test i can thing of would be the following test. It tests that `Amount` contains the value returned from the service after method `UpdateBackingAcc` was executed.

```
[TestMethod]
public void UpdateBackingAcc_WhenCalled_AmountContainsValueReturnedFromService()
{
    Mock<IService> serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
    const double expectedResult = 100;
    const int personId = 200;
    serviceMock.Setup(s => s.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(id => id == personId)))
        .Returns(() => expectedResult);
    Person person = new Person(personId, serviceMock.Object);

    // Act
    person.UpdateBackingAcc();

    // Assert
    double actualResult = person.Amount;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

Here we don't have all informations about the service. E.g. what does the service return when called with invalid `personId`? Considering this some more tests could be written, e.g.

- `UpdateBackingAcc_PersoneIdValid_AmountContainsValueReturnedFromService`
- `UpdateBackingAcc_PersoneIdInvalid_ThrowsException`

---

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public void UpdateBackingAcc_PersoneIdInvalid_ThrowsException()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IService> serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
    const int invalidPersonId = -1;
    serviceMock.Setup(s => s.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(i => i == invalidPersonId)))
        .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
    Person person = new Person(invalidPersonId, serviceMock.Object);

    // Act
    person.UpdateBackingAcc();

    // Assert
    // Throws exception
}
```

Comment: I think `Throws exception` is not responsibility of `Person` class.

Comment: @Fabio you are absolutely right! I was trying to theoretically consider the possibility when service receives invalid Id and throws exception. Please see edited answer.

Comment: No @dee, my point was that you don't need `try .. catch` at all. And of course you don't need to test it. If service will throw give it throw.

Comment: @Fabio thank you for your comments, I have edited the answer.